Manipulating Summations ∑ and telescopic sums in Lean 4
I want to prove the following lemma:
lemma my_lemma {α : Type} [Fintype α] (f g : α → ℚ) 
    (f_inj : Function.Injective f) 
    (h1 : ∀ a : α, 0 ≤ f a ∧ f a < 1 ) 
    (h2 : ∀ a b : α, f a < f b → f b - f a ≥ g a) 
    (h3 : ∀ a : α, g a ≤ 1 - f a) :
    ∑ a : α, g a ≤ 1 := by
  sorry

Before going into the logic of the proof, notice that injectivity allows us to lift the order from $\mathbb Q$.
The idea of the proof, in math, would be as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
 \sum_{a \in \alpha} g(a) &= g(a_{|\alpha|}) + \sum_{1 ≤ i < |\alpha|}g(a_i)\\
 &\leq 1 - f(a_{|\alpha|}) +  \sum_{1 ≤ i < |\alpha|}(f(a_{i+1}) - f(a_i)) &&;\text{by  } h_2, h_3\\
 &= 1 - f(a_1) &&;\;\text{telescopic}\\
 &\leq 1. &&;\; h_1
\end{aligned}
$$
I would like to understand how to write this proof in Lean 4 in the most idiomatic way.
I understand that his involves many steps. I appreciate any help.

I understand that to extract the largest element from the sum I can use Finset.sum_range_succ. But that is the only step that is clear to me.

It is a nice little formalization problem.  I might focus less on a clean idiomatic proof and instead on just the mathematical facts you need to prove this lemma, like that there is an ordering on the domain induced by injective functions, that this ordering leads to a recasting of your problem in terms of a sum over range, and the telescoping sum thing.  Some of these might be in Mathlib (use leansearch.net) but probably not in the exact form you need them.
